# Copy Secure PDF Fields To Non Secure PDF Programatically

Tags: javascript, c#, python, php, pdf

I know this is a long shot, but I am currently required to manually re-create 200+ fields from a secured PDF document to a non-secured PDF (both PDFs are exactly the same except for the secure permissions on one).

Is there a way of capturing each field (Properties) name,length height, etc and location/coordinate from the original PDF(secured) and then placing those fields on the non-secured PDF file programatically?

This will save me hours of work on a daily basis if there is a way to do this.

Here is an example of the form original form - https://dss.mo.gov/fsd/formsmanual/pdf/im-1ssl.pdf Once you save/Print the form to PDF the fields will be removed but the content remains.  It's at this point where we will need to re-created the fields.

*Note, we do not have access to change permissions of the original pdf.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

PDFFiller.com save the day. Uploaded the PDF document and PDFfiller mapped all the fields. Save as Fillable PDF document and done

Answer (score 0):

Sadly that old form had badly named fields. Here we can see Alimony and Loan were reversed!

[image]

So using any other tool like a PDFfiller would confuse the submissions office. Where ? presumably they automatically reversed the input values ! or else wonder why so many single students were claiming Alimony deductions.

What was needed is a derestricted copy:

[image]

Then it's easy to work direct with the FormDataFile for programmable inputs and outputs

[image]

However it's academic as the form is now totally rebuilt with Alimony now in the correct box for programmable entry: https://dssmanuals.mo.gov/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/IM-1SSL-Fillable-Secured-6-24-21.pdf

[image]